# Multiple commands produce on flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

after we added imageNotification dixcode for flutter build ipa not working and got error like this Multiple commands produce '/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgrmoxpodmwmsaevziaqkpmvmfmo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts /iphoneos/FirebaseCoreInternal.framework' but we run flutter run it can work fine in our device is there any solution for this case

we are using xcode Version 14.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help guys, I tried this way and it worked for me, the file is in Pods => Podfile

> for pod 'Firebase/Messaging' I disabled it

```
target 'ImageNotification' do
  use_frameworks!
  #pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```